# Derivative of cross product wrt vector

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors

I have the following function: $f(\dot r, r)=(\dot r+\omega\times r)^2$ where $\omega$ is constant.
I need to find $\partial f/\partial r$, but I'm struggling to figure out how to derive $\omega\times r$, which I need to do in order to use the chain rule.

As far as I can tell, because $\omega$ is constant, $\partial /\partial r (\omega\times r)=\omega \times \partial r/\partial r=\omega \times I$, but this seems wrong - is the cross product of a vector and a matrix even defined, or am I missing something earlier in the calculation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the square of a vector mean in this case?

Comment: Wasn't mentioned explicitly, but I believe it is a dot product of the vector with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $r=\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i e_i$ where $\{e_i\}_{i=1,2,3}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $$\frac \partial {\partial r_j} \omega\times \sum_{i=1}^3 r_i e_i  = \omega \times e_j  $$  so the Jacobian of $r\in\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto \omega\times r\in\mathbb{R}^3 $ has column $j$ equal to  $\omega\times e_j$. You can also define the vector product of $\omega$ with a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R^{3\times 3}}$ in this way:
$$\omega \times [A_1|A_2|A_3] = [\omega\times A_1|\omega\times A_2|\omega\times A_3]$$
where $A_j\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is  $j$-column of $A$, so you have $\nabla_r \omega\times r = \omega \times I$.

Comment: By following your first suggestion, what I get is $\omega \times (1,1,1)$. However, $\partial r/\partial r$ should be a matrix, not a vector (I think). So what's happening here?

Comment: You got it wrong,  when I said that $\nabla_r \omega \times r = \omega \times I$, $I$ is the identity matrix. The resulting matrix $\omega \times I$ is the matrix that  has $j$-column equal to $\omega\times e_j$ that is a vector.

Comment: You're write, I summed up rows instead of joining up columns to form the matrix $I$. So my 2 questions are:
1. Were my original assumptions correct? i.e.: $\partial f/\partial r = 2(\dot r + \omega \times r)\cdot (\omega \times \partial r/\partial r)$?
2. You say I can define the cross product of a vector and a matrix this way, but is it genuinely defined? I've never come across something like this.

Comment: 1. yes 2. What does genuinely defined means? It is just a definition, I don't know if it is used somewhere. If you prefer you can write for $i=1,2,3$ $\partial f /\partial r_i = 2 (\dot{r} + \omega \times r)\cdot (\omega \times e_i)$.

Comment: What I meant by genuinely defined is that there must be an agreed-upon way to derive this function, and so it seems strange to me that we have to figure out a way to define this action.

Comment: Notice that $\omega \times I = skw(\omega)$ defined in the Wauzl's answer. And $\omega\times A = skw(\omega)\cdot A$ ($\cdot$ is the usual matrix product). So the definition is quite natural.

Comment: How could this answer be improved? I think I have provided the solution to you problem and also quickly answered in more than one comment. You can accept the answer you like most but I think to deserve at least a +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can express the cross product as a matrix multiplication by introducting the function
$$\operatorname{skw}\colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^{3\times 3}, \omega\mapsto\operatorname{skw}(\omega) = \begin{bmatrix}0&-\omega_3 &\omega_2\\\omega_3&0&-\omega_1\\-\omega_2&\omega_3&0\end{bmatrix},$$
that maps each 3D vector on a skew-symmetric matrix which encodes the cross product:
$$ a\times b = \operatorname{skw}(a)\cdot b $$
and of course
$$ \frac d{db}\bigl(\operatorname{skw}(a)\cdot b\bigr) = \operatorname{skw}(a). $$
In your terms this means
$$ \frac d{d r}\omega\times r = \frac d{d r} \operatorname{skw}(\omega)\cdot r = \operatorname{skw}(\omega).$$

---

In the following section I have derived the function $f$ that you gave with respect to $r$:

You write (assuming the squared vector means dot-multiplying it by itself)
$$f(r,\dot r) = (\dot r + \operatorname{skw}(\omega)\cdot r)^T\cdot(\dot r + \operatorname{skw}(\omega)\cdot r) $$
and finally get
\begin{align}
\frac\partial{\partial r} f(r,\dot r) &= 2(\dot r + \omega\times r)^T\cdot\operatorname{skw}(\omega) \\
&= 2 \bigl(\operatorname{skw}^T(\omega)\cdot(\dot r + \omega\times r)\bigr)^T \\
&= -2 \bigl(\operatorname{skw}(\omega)\cdot(\dot r + \omega\times r)\bigr)^T \\
&= -2 \bigl(\omega\times(\dot r + \omega\times r)\bigr)^T \\
\end{align}
because $\operatorname{skw}$ is antisymmetric.
Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ is, as usual, a 3D *row* vector. If you need the column vector, use $\nabla_rf$.

Comment: Maybe this works, but is a bit of an overkill, the question I have should be quite simple (surely it can't be this complicated to derive $\omega \times r$ by $r$ itself?)

Comment: Sorry, I derived $f$ with respect to $r$. Of course $\frac d{d r} \omega\times r = \operatorname{skw}(\omega)$, like I stated in my third equation (just with $a$ and $b$ in place of $\omega$ and $r$). See my edits.