# How to do $\frac{d}{d q} \|q^*_c \times q - q_I\|^2$ (quaternion)

Tags: derivatives, quaternions, cross-product

How to do the following 
$$\frac{d}{d q} \|q^*_c \times q - q_I\|^2,$$ 
where

1. $q$ : a unit quaternion, i.e., $q^Tq=1$
2. $\times$ : vector cross product
3. $q_I$ : $[0 \ \ 0 \ \ 0 \ \ 1]^T$, i.e., no rotation
4. $q^*_c$ : a constant unit quaternion

My effort is that it becomes

$$2(q^*_c \times q -q_I) \frac{d}{d q}(q^*_c \times q)=2(q^*_r \times q -q_I) q^*_c\times I_{4}.$$

The last part is from the following

[Derivative of cross product wrt vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490441/derivative-of-cross-product-wrt-vector)

It looks like the dimension is not correct, how to modify it?

And how to move onto the next step?

Thanks!

Comment: The cross product of two vectors makes sense, and the product of two quaternions makes sense, but what is the cross product of two quaternions? Also unsure what you mean by $\frac{d}{dq}$. The usual way to represent quaternions is essentially as a sum (scalar)+(vector), which I subscribe to. (In this setting, can I assume you mean $q_I$ to just be the scalar $1$? Usually the scalar component is listed first, not last.)

Comment: @runway44  cross product of two quaternions represents the product of two rotation matrices, i.e., successive rotation. Well the order of vector part and scalar part depends on different fields. You can define either ways.

Comment: Wouldn't the product of rotation matrices correspond to just the product of quaternions? I guess you're calling the product of quaternions the "cross product" of quaternions (maybe that's common in your field?) Also dunno what $d/dq$ means.

Comment: @runway44 $d/dq$ should be $\nabla_q$, i.e., take gradient.